# Stopping audio from playing ontop of eachother

Tags: java

```
public class Player
{
    private PlayList playList;
    public Track currentTrack;
    boolean stopped = false;


    public Player()
    {
        playList = new PlayList("audio");
    }


    public PlayList getPlayList()
    {
        return playList;
    }


    public void play()
    {
        stop();
        if(stopped = true){
            currentTrack.play();
            stopped = false;
        }

    }

    public void stop()
    {
        currentTrack.stop();
        currentTrack.rewind();
        stopped = true;
    }


    public void setTrack(int trackNumber)
    {
        currentTrack = playList.getTrack(trackNumber);
    }

    public String getTrackName()
    {
        return currentTrack.getName();
    }


    public String getTrackInfo()
    {
        getTrackName();
        currentTrack.getDuration();

        return getTrackName() + " (" + currentTrack.getDuration() + ") " + 

"seconds";
        }
    }
```

Im trying stop the audio from playing ontop of eachother. Very basic code (im learning basics haha) this is a school assignment btw. Everything is done except the audio keeps layering ontop of eachother instead of stopping the first audio that was played.

Comment: change `if(stopped = true){` to `if(stopped == true){`

Comment: or just `if(stopped)`

Comment: Neither of these did the trick :(